# How to fit my data to an ode

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

Here is system of ODEs and data, where I am trying to use the real data to estimate some governing parameters.

```
Eq1 = S'[t] == u*k - alpha*S[t]*I1[t] - u*S[t] - p*S[t]

Eq2 = I1'[t] == alpha*S[t]*I1[t] - (beta + u)*I1[t]

Eq3 = R1'[t] == beta*I1[t] - u*R1[t] + p*S[t]


mymodel =  ParametricNDSolveValue[{Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, S[0] == 5000, I1[0] == 1, 
   R1[0] == 0}, I1, {t, 0, 2012}, {u, k, p, alpha, beta}]

realdata = {{2000, 25}, {2001, 32}, {2002, 38}, {2003, 30}, {2004, 
    32}, {2005, 35}, {2006, 40}, {2007, 49}, {2008, 22}, {2009, 
    36}, {2010, 54}, {2011, 85}};

myfit = NonlinearModelFit[realdata, mymodel[u, k, p, alpha, beta][t], {{u, 0.009}, {k, 0.9}, {p, 0.01}, {alpha, 1}, {beta, 0.9}}, t];


plotfit = Plot[myfit[t], {t, 0, 2012}];
plotdata = ListPlot[realdata, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01]];
Show[plotfit, plotdata]
```

It is taking forever to excuate. Can you please suggest?

Comment: Substituting the initial parameter values into `mymodel` gives time function of order `10^-25`. If that's ok you should increase the WorkingPrecision!

Comment: @TahirKhan The model does not match the data. For which physical system do you want to find a model?

Comment: @Alex Trounev I want to fit 2nd equation of the model to real data.

Comment: @TahirKhan What do these equations describe?

Comment: @AlexTrounev these equations describes populations of susceptible (S), infected (I1) and recovered (R).

Comment: @TahirKhan Then see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find for this problem

```
mymodel[u_?NumberQ, k_?NumberQ, p_?NumberQ, alpha_?NumberQ, 
  beta_?NumberQ] := 
 Module[{S, I1, R1, t}, 
  First[I1 /. 
    NDSolve[{S'[t] == u*k - alpha*S[t]*I1[t] - u*S[t] - p*S[t], 
      I1'[t] == alpha*S[t]*I1[t] - (beta + u)*I1[t], 
      R1'[t] == beta*I1[t] - u*R1[t] + p*S[t], S[0] == 5000, 
      I1[0] == 1, R1[0] == 0}, {S, I1, R1}, {t, 0, 2012}]]]

realdata = {{2000, 25}, {2001, 32}, {2002, 38}, {2003, 30}, {2004, 
    32}, {2005, 35}, {2006, 40}, {2007, 49}, {2008, 22}, {2009, 
    36}, {2010, 54}, {2011, 85}};

myfit = NonlinearModelFit[realdata, 
   mymodel[u, k, p, alpha, beta][
    t], {{u, 0.1}, {k, 50}, {p, 0.01}, {alpha, 1}, {beta, 0.009}}, t];
myfit["ParameterTable"]
plotfit = 


Plot[myfit[t], {t, 0, 2012}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, -500}];

plotdata = ListPlot[realdata, PlotStyle -> {Orange, PointSize[0.01]}];
Show[plotfit, plotdata]
    Show[Plot[myfit[t], {t, 2000, 2012}, PlotRange -> {20, 85}], plotdata]
```

[image: fig1]